# vscode: how to setup debugging mono/c#?

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/debugging ) to debug c#/mono on win8. I have also installed the latest version of mono.

I added a config to launch.json and changed the 'type' to mono(also tried pointing 'program' at the debug exe) but I just get the error:

initialize: can't create debug session for adapter ID "mono"

how do you setup debugging on a c# project?

edit: seems like a gulp script may be required? [Compiling C# projects with VSCode on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956171/compiling-c-sharp-projects-with-vscode-under-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment48035420_29956171)

Comment: you debug by setting up your default language, then you set some break points.. then click `F5` also do a MSDN Windows 8 Debugger google search

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to debug a simple console application on Windows 7. Running with dnx is no problem. Any more feedback on this one?

Comment: Not exactly mono, but there is a VS Code extension now for coreCLR https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: and possibly this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.mono-debug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Visual Studio Code: Preview currently does not support mono debugging on Windows**. Debugging mono is only supported for Linux and Mac at the moment.
Node debugging is supported on Windows, Linux and Mac.

Comment: I believe you since it doesn't seem to work :) did they mention this in one of the videos? The only page I found that mentioned compatibility addressed the debugging that didn't work in linux yet

Comment: I'll add it to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/debugging now ;) not sure when we update the site though

Comment: Latest version also shows a message when trying to attach `Mono debugging not supported on Windows`.