# Compiling C# projects with VSCode on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, visual-studio-code

I set up VSCode on Ubuntu 14.04 according to the various tutorials available in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs) - I tried as many as I could make sense of. The editor runs without issue and (after working through Mono version discrepancies) provides a superior coding experience as compared to most of the alternatives in my opinion.

My issue comes when trying to compile my C# project. This is functionality that I would have expected when completing the Getting Started guide. After hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> I'm initially prompted to create a `tasks.json` file which looks to provide project specific configuration of shortkey actions. From comments in the initial `tasks.json` generated, it appears to be targeting Windows and refers to a `tsc.exe` program which is a TypeScript compiler.

I've spent a little time building projects with MonoDevelop on the same laptop but never had to setup the compilation step. Am I wrong in assuming this should be functionality available out of the box, or have I missed a step for properly handling C# projects?

Comment: might be a wild guess here but what about `v8dotnet` project and trying to bind that as the TS compiler ?

Comment: @Pogrindis - While VSCode seems to think I'm trying to build a TypeScript project, I'm actually trying to build a C# project. Are you suggesting that `v8dotnet` is required to build C# projects?

Comment: ahh sorry, I thought you were working with some c# server side but with typescript front end.. Im even more confused now!

Comment: Upvoted for alerting me to the existence of a Microsoft supported Linux C# IDE

Comment: @Asad - Thanks for the upvote. It sounds like you think this is a bad idea but in the end we're all just one big happy (and dysfunctional) family.

Comment: I don't actually know *why* this is happening, but you should be able to fix that error by getting the typescript compiler from `npm`. If you don't have Node.js, use `apt-get install node`, then use `npm install -g typescript`. Not sure why it needs `tsc` to compile C#. I'll leave posting an actual 'Answer' to someone who can explain what is going on.

Comment: Can you run `tsc` in the command line? You'll probably want to use `-g` when installing it so that Visual Studio Code can trigger it, no?

Comment: One of the pages mentions msbuild support, but I don't think it said whether it was win only

Comment: Thanks @ChromableedStudios. From what I've found it is indeed Win only, though I would love to hear otherwise.

Comment: I just got it working on my Mac. Perhaps the same settings will do on your system. I wrote it down on my blog: [Compile a Visual Studio solution in Visual Studio Code on OSX](http://blog.denouter.net/2015/04/compile-visual-studio-solution-in.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I must have been impatient when looking through the default `tasks.json` file last night. There is a section that refers to msbuild (towards the bottom):

```json
// Uncomment the section below to use msbuild and generate problems 
// for csc, cpp, tsc and vb. The configuration assumes that msbuild 
// is available on the path and a solution file exists in the  
// workspace folder root. 
/* 
{   
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "msbuild",
    "args": [
        // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.       
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"  
    ],
    "taskSelector": "/t:",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.            
            "showOutput": "silent",
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings          
            // and infos in the output.
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }   
     ] 
 }
*/
```

Just comment out the rest of the file, uncomment the above JSON text, and change "command" from "msbuild" to "xbuild" (the Mono equivalent). Now hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> successfully compiles the project.

Hopefully, this manual tinkering with configuration files will be less necessary or tedious once it comes out of preview.

*EDIT*

Marking this as answer for now. Will update or accept a better answer should things change during the evolution of the product.

Comment: or hopefully this manual tinkering will still be around but not be the default mode of interaction would be my vote

Comment: For anyone reading this today, the JSON is identical; the key part, mentioned in this answer, is to change `command` from `msbuild` to `xbuild`.